# How can i render two jsx files using ReactDOM.render

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, gulp, browserify

As i said t want to render two jsx files using ReactDOM.render, but i don't know how can i do it.

```
import Header from './header';
import HelloWorld from './hello-world';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


ReactDOM.render(
<Header />,
<HelloWorld />,
document.querySelector('.root')
);
```

Many thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 4):

`render` can only render one component (which can have children). So like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Header />
    <HelloWorld />
  </div>,
  document.querySelector('.root')
);
```

Comment: Work great !! Thanks a lot David Gilbertson !